# File does not exist or is not executable: bin/phantomjs

Tags: php, javascript, phantomjs, парсер

Установил PhantomJS на MAMP, сделал все что мне необходимо - не было никаких проблем, все работает как часы, однако стоило мне после импортировать папку с исходниками на хостинг - вылетает следующая ошибка:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'JonnyW\PhantomJs\Exception\ProcedureFailedException' with message 'Error when executing PhantomJs procedure "default" - File does not exist or is not executable: bin/phantomjs' in /home/gorecky/hotshoppingdeals.net/omlife/vendor/jonnyw/php-phantomjs/src/JonnyW/PhantomJs/Procedure/Procedure.php:132 Stack trace: #0 /home/gorecky/hotshoppingdeals.net/omlife/vendor/jonnyw/php-phantomjs/src/JonnyW/PhantomJs/Client.php(170): JonnyW\PhantomJs\Procedure\Procedure->run(Object(JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client), Object(JonnyW\PhantomJs\Message\Request), Object(JonnyW\PhantomJs\Message\Response)) #1 /home/gorecky/hotshoppingdeals.net/omlife/index.php(81): JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client->send(Object(JonnyW\PhantomJs\Message\Request), Object(JonnyW\PhantomJs\Message\Response)) #2 {main} thrown in /home/gorecky/hotshoppingdeals.net/omlife/vendor/jonnyw/php-phantomjs/src/JonnyW/PhantomJs/Procedure/Procedure.php on line 132

Мой код в файле index.php выглядит следующим образом:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

  $client = \JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client::getInstance();
  $request = $client->getMessageFactory()->createRequest($link, 'GET');
  $response = $client->getMessageFactory()->createResponse();
  $client->send($request, $response); 
  $html = $response->getContent();
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: "*File does not exist or is not executable: `bin/phantomjs`*" -- у вас там PhantomJS установлен вообще?

Comment: Перед тем как задать вопрос вы проверили то, что написано в ошибке - что bin/phantomjs существует и является исполняемым?

Comment: Прошу прощения, если вопрос показался вам глупым, дело в том, что я устанавливал PhantomJS на локалке MAMP, и там никаких ошибок собственно не было! Я был уверен, что для работы на хостинге достаточно скопировать папку с проектом (где phantom предустановлен).

Comment: @Naumov Прошу прощения, не подскажите где это сделать, где выполнить эту команду?) спасибо!

Comment: @ArtyomSosonko, лучше нигде не выполняйте эту команду в том виде, как она приведена. это действительно очень вредный совет.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin при данных обстоятельствах никто незнае путь до приложения абсолютный

Comment: @Naumov, вы же как раз и попробовали указать, прихватив заодно и ещё кучу файлов (если каталог bin где-то там существует). вместо того, чтобы посоветовать, как найти конкретный файл и выполнить для него `chmod +x путь/к/файлу`.

Comment: @Naumov давать права на все файлы подряд это ужасная идея, особенно не зная её содержимого.